# A negation of convergence statement for subsequences

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Given the following definition: A number $c$ is a ${\bf limit \; point}$ of the sequence $\{ a_n \}$ if there exists a subsequence $\{ a_{n_k} \}$ such that $\lim_{k \to \infty} a_{n_k} = c$. Let $S$ be the set of all limit points of $(a_n)$.

Im trying to understand precisely what $x \notin S$ means in terms of quantifiers.

### thought:

It means that $\exists \epsilon > 0$ so that $\forall N$ we can always find $n > N$ so that $|a_{n_k} - x | \geq \epsilon $ and in particular $|a_n - x | \geq \epsilon$ because $a_{n_k}$ is any subsequence of $a_n$

Is my thought process correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are given $(a_n)$ and told that $x$ is not a limit point. No subsequence $(a_{n_k})$ is given to you. So your interpretation is not correct.

The correct interpretations is there exists $\epsilon >0$ and a positive  integer $m$  such that $|a_n -x| >\epsilon$ for all $n>m$. [Existence of  a subsequence converging to $x$ is equivalent to the fact that for every $\epsilon >0$ the inequality $|a_n-x| <\epsilon$ holds for infinitely many values of $n$].

Comment: isnt the negation of there exists a subsequence: for any subsequence such that ....

Comment: You can say for every subsequence $a_{n_k})$ there exists  further subsequence such that $|a_{n_k}_j-x| >\epsilon$ but that ti too complicated.

Comment: I think you have a mistake in third line: You say existence of subsequence converging to $x$ is: $\forall \epsilon >0 \exists N >0 \forall n > N \implies |a_n-x| <\epsilon$. however, the negation should be: there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $N$ there is an $n>N$ so that $|a_n - x | > \epsilon $

Comment: @Theoneandonly No, what I have written is correct. For example suppose $a_n=\frac  1n$ for $n$ even and $1$ for $n$ odd.  Take $x=0$. The the condition you have written is satisfied even though $x$ is  a limit point.